# Dealing with Time in Php/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im very confused. For example I'm adding a record which time should be also filled up, then I filled up the the time textbox with format like this 6:30 pm.

`So how could I store this data into mysql database? What data type should I use?Because there are time,datetime and timestamp datatypes. What PHP functions should I use.`

What exactly I wanted to achieve is to get user inputted time with the format H:MM am/pm (e.g 6:30 pm), store it in a database the proper way, and display or retrieve this data with formatting exactly the way it was entered.

Could anyone please help me understand how to store and retrieve times in mysql using Php. Please give me examples.

I know there are so many resources on the web, but I want direct and clear answers for just a newbie like me in programming.

Comment: Normalise the time you want to store to ISO8601 (http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). There are useful JavaScript libraries for that (e.g. dojo). If you are storing time in your DB, use the `time` datatypes.

Comment: @DipeshParmar that's very bad advise. A database should use the datatypes available. You will run into problems later if you don't thnk it through.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you take the time as `6:30 PM` as user input then you can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to convert it to a timestamp, which you can then format for storage in the database.

Use the MySQL `TIME` data type which requires the time format in HH:MM:SS (24 hour).

Example:

```
$dbFormat = date('H:i:s', strtotime('6:30 PM'));
```

Produces:

> 18:30:00

This is ready to insert into the database. When you retrieve it from the database, you can have MySQL format it back to the original format using the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(mytime, '%l:%i %p') FROM mytable
```

Produces:

> 6:30 PM

Comment: I applied your example
`$dbFormat = date('H:i:s', strtotime($timeinput));`
for inserting the time into the database

And i used this for outputting:
`$time = date('g:i a',strtotime($timeinput));`

And all goes well!

Answer (score 4):

You could use timestamp to store your time in the MySQL database.

Time to timestamp:

```
<?php
    $time = strtotime($yourTime); //yourTime is the time from your input box.
?>
```

Timestamp to time:

```
<?php
    $time = date('g:i a', $yourTime); //yourTime is the time from the database.
?>
```

For more information see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

**Edit:**
You can save a timestamp value as INT(11) in your MySQL database.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the type **time** in mysql
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html

The time is stored in this format: ***HH:MM:SS***

And for php converting,

Insert:

```
$time=strtotime('6:30 pm');
$data_bd=date("H:i:s",$time);
//And then insert into mysql field
```

Extract:

```
//Extract the data from mysql
$time=strtotime('18:30:00');
$data_print=date("g:i a",$time);
```

If you want to see the process: http://codepad.org/gNdm4YIy

---

For more information:

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like that:

```
$time = '6:30pm';
$newTime = strftime('%H:%M:%S',strtotime($time));
```

Now you should get a valid mysql time.

Mostly its the best idea to store data to mysql database with the right format. If you only have timedata here i recommend the time-format for that column. datetime and timestamp you should only use if u have full dates with time-parts like 2012-12-05 09:54:32 (or as timestamp 1354697672).

To load the time data and to format it back into 00:00am/pm format you can try:

```
$time = '18:30:00';
$newTime = strftime('%I:%M %p',strtotime($time));
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Could you explain to me what does the percent sign do?

Comment: The percent sign informs strftime that the following character is to be translated in some way, rather than displayed verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your applications (do you want time-in-a-day, or absolute time?, do you want to do arithmetic?, etc).

A simple solution could be this:

Use the [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) and [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) functions:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("6:30 pm");
$timestring = strftime("%I:%M %P", $timestamp);
```

The `$timestamp` is seconds since epoch and you can store it as a INT in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL timestamp with format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). You need to save the time in a 24-Hour format. If you just save it as 0000-00-00 18:30:00.

And then when you're retrieving the time just use date('h:i A', $mysql_timestamp) to format it to 6:30 PM.

Hope that helps.